# Postgres - Looking to create a new table/rows for each item in existing tables (jsonb)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, pgadmin

I have a 308 table db in Postgresql (v13,15 installed) and each table consists of an id,meta, and data column. Im primarily using pgadmin 4 v6.19. Every data column is jsonb with varying lengths b/w tables. I am trying to take the data column and build a new table with each in a separate db, naming the table with the same table name and having the keys of the json in the data column become the new columns in the new table. Essentially a more human readable setup.

I'm finding it hard to loop through all tables  and actually be able to use the data on any given row. I've used information_schema.columns and information_schema.tables and get more of an overview than anything. The big issue I run into is being unable to use a variable in a SELECT statement.

Im trying a double loop since i cant seem to the get the data from using the all tables search and i cant get the name of the table without that search. The table_rec.table_name,name variables that are logged both resolve to the name of the test_table, but when dropped into the select statement above...I get the telltale 'relation does not exist' error. Even if i can create a table, im still struggling as to how i would get the individual columns and types to use in 'create table'. I mostly do this type of thing from node.js and predominantly am a frontend guy. Any suggestions helps. Thanks in advance!

````
DECLARE
rec record;
name varchar;
table_rec record;

BEGIN



FOR table_rec IN 
        SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name,column_default,data_type
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE column_name='data'
        ORDER BY table_name ASC
    LOOP
    
    SELECT table_name
         INTO name
         FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_name=table_rec.table_name;
    
            RAISE NOTICE '%: %: %: %: %', table_rec.table_schema, table_rec.table_name, table_rec.column_name,table_rec.column_default,table_rec.data_type;
        
            FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM "1cw9vxxv"
                LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'data %, %, %, %, %', rec.id,rec.meta,rec.data, table_rec.table_name,name;
                END LOOP;
    
--EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE refined.%I (id SERIAL NOT NULL, data CHAR(MAX))',rec.data);
        
END LOOP;
END$$;```
````

Comment: You have to scan all rows in a table, unnest the JSON and aggregate the columns somehow. It is a good idea to get rid of that data model!